# Change session keys in new chain spec

Tags: nodes, chainspec, session

Chain spec `primary_chain` is defined under `node/src/chain_spec.rs`

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. generate default chain spec for `primary_chain`

```
./collator build-spec --chain primary_chain > spec.json
```

1. Edit `session.keys` array with updated sets of keys
2. Generate genesis-state for updated chain state

```
./collator export-genesis-state --chain spec.json
```

**Error:**

```
Error: thread 'main' panicked at 'Validator in session 1 missing keys!', /home/deployer/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/fc3fd07/frame/session/src/lib.rs:487:52
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to modifier the [code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a88f75eb54414405ffa785072d38548793f0009e/bin/node/cli/src/chain_spec.rs#L90-L170), then re-generate the chain spec.

If you modify the chain spec json file directly, you might need to update all the related pallets.